# prometheus: not getting all containers when using kube pod container resource requests cpu cores

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am using prometheus to get the container resource request cpu cores. I am using the follwing code:

```
kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores
```

I am getting all the containers except one.

I used docker ps and i am seeing the container is started.

any idea why I am not getting  the container in  prometheus result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your container/pod request a CPU? As I've noticed this metric shouldn't return a value when the container/pod doesn't have the following: `spec.containers[].resources.requests.cpu` in its deployment or other kinds of objects where the container is defined.